# How do I view the file structure of a Wordpress blog hosted on Bluehost

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, blogs, bluehost, nextgen-gallery

First off I'm new to web stuff, so sorry if this question doesn't make sense.  I created a Wordpress blog on Bluehost and would like to know how I go about viewing the file structure of my site.  Everything I can find on the web references something called [cPanel](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2236), but when I log into my site, I see a Bluehost *Portal*, but nothing called *cPanel*.

Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out where my media library is stored so that I can have my NextGEN gallery store its photos in the default Wordpress media library.  Is it possible to have the NextGEN gallery plugin use the default media library so that I don't have mulitple copies of everything?

Any general info on how the files in a Wordpress/Bluehost site are structured would also be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your hosting plan. some hosting plans offer a file manager. In the case of bluehost, that file manager is cpanel. The file manager lets you navigate through the files located in the back end (developer end) of your website. Some hosting plans do not offer a file manager. Likewise, some hosting plans only offer the ability to create a wordpress website where wordpress will take care of everything, including database handling and file managing.

However, you can always install and use the wordpress plugin WP File Manager. This plugin will let you navigate through your files from your wordpress account. See link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for managing your website files:

- The first option is cPanel which is the most control panel used by companies.
- The second option is FTP Application available for all companies.

Both options need "login credential" try to check your email or ask support to provide it to you.

For the first option. Try to login to your cPanel by typing your domainname.com:2082 or domainname.com/cpanel on your browser URL.

change "domainname.com" to your domain name!

For the second option. search for FTP Application and download it then use your login credential to login.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to view the file structure of your WordPress is to login to cPanel and click on File Manager. You can see the directory structure of WordPress under the public_html directory.